# Aplicação ASP.Net MVC não se conecta ao banco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo uma *solution* na aula de programação orientada à objeto para web. Vamos criar um sistema de controle de estoque. Uma das primeiras "telas" de acesso, é o login, só que nesse momento, minha 'aplicação' inteira já vai por água abaixo.

Na primeira tela, temos o campo de login e senha, quando clicamos no botão 'login' é chamado um método, que faz a consulta do login no banco, porém o retorno é sempre 'Login invalido'

Método `FazLogin`

```
        return Contexto.tblUsuario
        .Where(u => u.LOGIN == usuario && u.SENHA == senha).FirstOrDefault() != null;
```

Através do próprio Visual Studio, se fizermos uma consulta no banco de dados, consigo enxergar a tabela `tblUsuario` e também consigo ver meus usuários para teste. Na connection string, está desta forma:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ModeloEstoqueContextoContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModeloEstoqueContexto.csdl|res://*/ModeloEstoqueContexto.ssdl|res://*/ModeloEstoqueContexto.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LENOVO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ESTOQUE_DATABASE;user id=sa;password=SENHAXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Estamos trabalhando no modelo MVC, e sim, as referências já foram checadas várias e várias vezes, tanto por mim, quanto pelo professor.

---

@Cigano, o Metadata (Connection String) é gerado automaticamente pelo Entity Framework

@pnet, A senha não está criptografada, é uma coisa bem simples que estamos fazendo na faculdade, ao digitar a senha, temos um response.Redirect que direciona para a outra página. Ao fazer o 'debug' sempre o 'count = 0' e os valores são nulos.

Não estou conseguindo pegar o controller aqui.

Comment: Esta `connetion string` está muito suspeita. Qual a necessidade de passar o Metadata nela?

Comment: Cara, uma pergunta. No seu banco a senha está criptografada? Caso esteja, seria necessário descriptografar para fazer a comparação. Outra coisa, debugando o seu return, está vindo alguma coisa? Pode postar a sua controller, para podermos entender melhor? Assim é mais fácil. Quanto ao comentário do Morrison, isso é normal mesmo, pois o Entity já monta ele assim, com os Metadatas. Comigo também é assim e funciona corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, eu fiz uma tela simples de login com MVC e trabalhei assim. Construir na controller um método que pegasse no banco o cara logado, como você faz. Aí então, serializava a informação através de um JsonResult e enviava a uma função jquery que fazia a desserelização do resultado da linq, validava e então chamava a tela correspondente. Era assim que fiz e nunca me deu dor de cabeça. Veja abaixo os códigos.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ValidaLogin(string _email, string _senha)
        {
            INETGLOBALEntities db = new INETGLOBALEntities();

            EncriptyDecripty cripto = new EncriptyDecripty();

            string s = cripto.Encrypt(_senha);

              var  result_login = (from login in db.tbl_usuario
                                    where login.email == _email && login.senha_usuario == _senha
                                    select new { login.email, login.nm_usuario }).ToList();

             if(result_login.Count > 0)
             {
                return Json(new { result_login }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

             }
             else
             {
                return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
             }
        }
```

Jquery:

```
function ValidaLogin() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Login/ValidaLogin',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ _email: $('#inputEmail').val(), _senha: $('#inputPassword').val() }),
        success: function (data) {

            $(data.result_login).each(function () {
                if (this.email != '' || this.email != null)
                    $(window.document.location).attr('href', '/Pesquisa/Pesquisa');
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {

            alert('Usuário ou senha digitados de forma incorreta.');
        }
    });
}
```

É isso, e nunca me deu pau trabalhando dessa forma.